# Problem 5.14 in Fulton's Algebraic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The problem reads as follows:
[image]

**Question 1:** Any hints on how to approach that?

Next, consider Theorem 1 of Chapter 5 of the same reference:
[image]

**Question 2:** It seems to me that the argument of the proof
of "case 1" holds for any multiplicities $r_1,\dots,r_n$, since 
the existence of these lines does not depend on the $r_i$. This
would imply that for any $r_1,\dots,r_n$ the dimension of
$V(d;r_1P_1,\dots,r_nP_n)$ drops at least by $n$. Am i correct?

Comment: To get you off the ground: two points determine a unique line, so there are only $n-1$ lines through $P_1$ which hit any of $P_2$ through $P_n$. So just take lines through points in the complement of these $n-1$ lines; their complement is open, thus dense, and certainly infinite.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: That's a good point, thanks.

Comment: And the same reasoning allows you to discard the tangent line of $F$ at that point.

Comment: @Hoot: Right...